# loop values to a specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, formatting

I'm trying to populate an array in the format. It is a specific format that another library uses and must be exact:

```
var d1 = [[1,3], [2,7], [3,5], [4,6], [5,5]];
```

I have a database that I want to use for the 'y' values. How can I use a loop to get the values into this specific format? Something similar to this (but not this because this isn't working):
    var x, y, d1 =[];
    for (i=0; i

Any thoughts appreciated.

***EDIT***

After taking your advice I initialised the array properly and changed i++ to i+1. Now if I use `console.log(d1);`

I get this:

```
[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
```

Comment: What database you have? How you gonna take values from it?

Comment: Don't use `toString`, because that's what it'll put out. To see what the actual array looks like, either use `console.log(d1);` or, if you want the string: `console.log(JSON.stringify(d1))`. Also: accept one of the answers, that's the SO way of saying thanks ;-)

Comment: If you get `[Array[2],Array[2],Array[2]]`, you'll get a little triangle, too. click it to see the array objects in full (including their prototypes and magic `length` property)

Comment: What's the problem with the result `[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]` ? I think you're confusing what it is with how it looks in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = 0, y = 0, d1 = [];
for (i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  x= i+1;      
  y=array[i];
  d1.push([x, y]);
}
```

`var x = 0, y = 0, d1 = [];`  initialize `d1` to array
`x= i+1;` else you will increment the value of i and your loop won't be good (incrementing of 2 every iteration)
`d1.push([x, y]);` remove the coma that was not supposed to be here

Comment: console.log(d1.toString());       1,73.4,2,73.4,3,73.4,4,73.4,5,73.4,6,73.4,7,73.4... This isn't the right format!

Comment: d1 is an array. If you `toString` it you will have that display. But this is not the display that interest us. The variable structure [[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]] is what you want and what you have with this code. try a console.log(d1) instead of toString.

Comment: Proof is: `[[1,3], [2,7], [3,5], [4,6], [5,5]].toString();` => "1,3,2,7,3,5,4,6,5,5"

Comment: I'm getting this... [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]

Comment: In chrome it shows that, in Firebug it would be another display. But the structure is what you want. An array of array containing 2 values, x and y for indexes 0 and 1. The "display" is not what matters, the structure is.

Answer (score 2):

Just initiate `d1` to an array and your code should work, if you remove the falty `,`, too. You're also incrementing `i` twice, once on each iteration of the loop, and once on assigning it to `x`

```
var x, y, d1 = [];//assign empty array
for (i=0; i<array.length; i++)//leave this increment as is
{
    x= i+1;//don't increment i, just assign i + 1
    y=array[i];
    d1.push([x, y]);//<== remove ,
}
```

By not assigning an empty array to `d1`, the statement `d1.push([x,y]);` translates to: `undefined.push([x,y])`, which is wrong, of course.

You're also not declaring `i`, so it might be an implied global, so add

```
var x, y, i, d1 = [];
```

To see the actual output, instead of using `console.log(d1.toString)`, which will flatten the array, use either

```
console.log(d1);
//or to get a string:
console.log(JSON.stringify(d1));
```

Comment: @dievardump: right you are, edit made, had spotted several issues, but missed that one (I get hung up on implied globals, so I missed the double increment)